# SQL query - making change to multiple result

Tags: sql

I'm still very new to this so forgive me. I'm normally a 2nd deskside support engineer for general PC issues, but due to being out of work thought I would try and expand my skillset.

I have a statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `Colour` LIKE 'Red' AND `Location` LIKE 'London-My'
```

This returns a handful of results.

How do I then change these results say to change the value of (for example) Location: London-My to a new location(Say London Docklands)?

Sorry to ask, I can find how to change multiple values but not from a multi value result as above.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you meant by "change multiple values", but

if you wanted to actually update the data:

```
UPDATE `TABLE 1` 
   SET `Location` = 'London Docklands'
 WHERE `Colour` LIKE 'Red' 
   AND `Location` LIKE 'London-My'
```

if you just needed to change the values in the returned resultset:

```
SELECT 'London Docklands' AS `Location`,
       `Colour`
       -- other needed columns go here
  FROM `TABLE 1` 
 WHERE `Colour` LIKE 'Red' 
   AND `Location` LIKE 'London-My'
```

Comment: What I meant my multi value result was I know how to change all values of  a particular single result ie: London-My or All colours with Blue value(through the tutorials) but not like above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 SET Location = 'London Docklands' WHERE 
     Location in (SELECT Location FROM TABLE_1 WHERE Location LIKE 'London-My')
```

Comment: This didn't work, came back with error. I'm currently practicing using PhpMyadmin demo server on it's website with some data I loaded if this matters.